# TradingView HeikenAhi algorithm

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I try to calculate heiken ashi OHLC on tradingview panel .
Please note:
[image]

this picure is for `ADAUSDTPERP` at 21/Oct/2021 (Daily Timeframe)
left side is normal candle and right is Heiken Ashi.
OHLC of second candle (Left side) is :

```
O: 2.1121   
H: 2.2102    
L: 2.0939 
C: 2.1924
```

According to Heiken Ashi algorithm :
Open = (Open(Previous candle) + Close(Previous candle))/2

so :

```
(2.1121 + 2.1924)/2 = 2.15225
```

but in tradingview heiken ashi Open candle by `2.1470` ! (last candle right side)
How tradingview calculate that ?
I miss somethings ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Open = (Open(Previous candle) + Close(Previous candle))/2
```

To calculate the heikin ashi open value take into account the previous values of haOpen and haClose instead of regular candle's open and close. Use the regular candle values only on the very first bar to calculate the first value in the series, as is shown below:

```
float haClose = ohlc4
var float haOpen = na

if barstate.isfirst
    haOpen := (open + close) / 2
else
    haOpen := (nz(haOpen[1]) + nz(haClose[1])) / 2
```

You can find the open-source example that match the built-in Tradingview's HA candles in the public library: https://www.tradingview.com/script/qRNix8Bh-Heiken-Ashi-Candles/